# Power factor in a power system

Tags: power, ac, frequency, power-factor-correction

Will a system necessarily have an increase or decrease in power factor with a change in frequency of the system?

Comment: [This should](https://www.osti.gov/pages/servlets/purl/1435710) help. Click green button at bottom for the paper.  Discusses frequency dependent loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power factor is the ratio between power a circuit actually consumes, and the product of the rms voltage across a circuit and the rms current through the circuit.

There are at least two types of effects that cause power factor to be less than unity.

1. Phase difference between voltage and current
2. Harmonics in the current

Reactive components, i.e. capacitors and inductors, and components that have capacitance and/or inductance such as transformers and motors, may cause the voltage and current to be out phase. This results in a power factor less than unity. Inductors and capacitors are reactive components, and in a certain way, their effects are opposite of one another. A circuit that has inductive reactance (at a certain frequency) may have that inductive reactance "canceled" by adding capacitance. If the capacitive reactance exactly equals the inductive reactance, the power factor will be unity (neglecting the other source of low power factor, i.e. harmonics). This effect is frequency dependent, however, because the reactance of a capacitor decreases with frequency, while the reactance of an inductor increases with frequency. So, power factor correction caused by phase shift may be implemented by adding a capacitor (usually) or an inductor (less usually), but this only works for a given frequency.

Note that all real circuits have capacitive and inductive components, even if just in the wiring.

Low power factor due to harmonics arises in the following way. The current is in phase with the voltage, but the waveform is not sinusoidal. This occurs frequently when a power supply rectifies AC and smooths the result with a capacitor or capacitors. The rectifiers only conduct during the peaks of the AC voltage. There are both active and passive techniques to reduce harmonic effects. These techniques may work over a fairly broad range of frequencies. However, like in all circuits, there are limits. If the AC frequency is too far from the frequency range the power factor correction circuits were designed for, their effectiveness will decrease.

So the short answer is, in theory, a change in frequency will always affect power factor. In practice, a change in frequency will have great effect in some circuits, while other circuits may experience a change in frequency over a broad range with minimal changes in power factor.

Comment: so does that mean even in a circuit with near-unity power factor unity it may not necessarily maintain that power factor when there is a change in frequency? If the change is not due to reactive components, are there other explanations for it?

Comment: I have given a major rewrite to my answer to address your question. Please let me know if it is understandable and answers your question.

Comment: A short answer to this has been given in the comments from the first answer but this answer explains in greater detail. Thanks! much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will. The reactive power and hence power factor depends on the reactance of the capacitors and inductors in the system these are dependant on frequency
\$1 \over 2\pi fC\$ and \$2\pi fL\$ respectively.

Comment: what if the power factor is 1, will it be affected by frequency? Since power factor of 1 means there is no reactance to begin because there are no capacitance and inductance components to begin with. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I think you have a typo in reactance expressions. It's the other way (reciprocals).

Comment: @Mitu Raj thanks you are right editing.

Comment: You are quite correct but if you have no capacitors or inductors in the system why would you be concerned with power factor?

Comment: The capacitive and inductive reactance's can balance to give you a pf of 1. In that case it will change with frequency. But didn't you ask about the case where  there are no capacitance and inductance components to begin with?

Comment: No sorry for the misunderstanding, I wasn't asking for when there are no reactive components, i was only making an example for when pf is unity, what i meant was if pf is 1 will it still be affected by frequency and i think you already answered it!